# HowTo update Spring Boot dependencies correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I'm working on an multi project with Eclipse Neon and Gradle 4.
Spring Boot is used and also **spring-boot-gradle-plugin**.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.15.0",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE"
    }

}
```

Using the `gradle.properties` file one can steer the versions to be used.
Today I switched Spring to `spring.version=4.3.10.RELEASE`.
I used Eclipse > Gradle > Gradle Refresh Project more than once.
The **gradle-version-plugin** still complains about a newer version of one of the dependencies.

```
com.sun.mail:javax.mail [1.5.6 -> 1.6.0]
```

This dependency comes from [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) and as you can see, should be 1.6.0 now as a default.
I just do not specify this version because of **spring-boot-gradle-plugin**.

```
compile "com.google.guava:guava:${project.'google.guava.version'}",
        "joda-time:joda-time",
        "com.sun.mail:javax.mail"
```

My expectation is that after a Gradle Refresh this dependency should be resolved correctly.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error ?

Comment: spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE depends on spring-boot-loader-tools:1.5.4.RELEASE and this depends on spring->4.3.9.RELEASE. Why do you want to change the version of spring that came with the package?

Comment: There is no error show, but it's not using the newest javax.mail version. @elysrivero99 So this means regardless if I specify Spring 4.3.10 the boot-loader-tools will use 4.3.9 dependencies?

Comment: @Nabor Yes, I think so.

Comment: Okay, I can manually set the newer version, the same way I did it for Spring. So it's not a big problem. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You are discussing transitive dependencies and you can control those with gradle. I recommend reading up on `Dependency Management` from Gradle Docs:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

You can do something like this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.sun.mail' && details.requested.name == 'javax.mail') {
            details.useVersion '1.6.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not discussing transitive dependencies. As one can see in the excerpt from the build.gradle, javax.mail is referenced directly and not as a transitive dependency. We discussed spring-boot-gradle-plugin and the reason for the behaviour is clarified...